# Optional validation in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, validation-controls

I have a page with three radio buttons, depending on which button is selected I need to validate some controls (using required field validators). Other than using custom validators, is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Validators offer a [client-side API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside) that allows you to :

- validate client side
- Hook up validators client side.
- Enable or disable client side validators.

The syntax of the `ValidatorEnable` function is :

```
 ValidatorEnable(rfvMyValidator, boolState);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an OnSelectedIndexChanged to the RadioButtonList (or CheckedChanged if they're individual Radio button controls)

In the code behind, `.Enable` & `.Disable` the specific required field validators.

Comment: ... which will require a noticeable postback unless Ajax-ified!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually I want this to work client side too, seems like custom validators are the only way

Comment: You can enable/disable Validator controls with client side javascript as well... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside - search that page for the `ValidatorEnable` function

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on a small example and it worked for me:

I have

-2textboxes: TextBox1 and TextBox2

-RequiredFieldValidator : RequiredFieldValidator1 with ControlToValidate="TextBox1"

-RadioButton : RequiredFieldValidator1

This code is generated by the RequiredFiledValidator:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var RequiredFieldValidator1 = document.all ? document.all["RequiredFieldValidator1"] : document.getElementById("RequiredFieldValidator1");
RequiredFieldValidator1.controltovalidate = "TextBox1";
RequiredFieldValidator1.errormessage = "RequiredFieldValidator";
RequiredFieldValidator1.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
RequiredFieldValidator1.initialvalue = "";
//]]>
</script>
```

I want when the user click on the RadioButton1 to switch the validation to TextBox2.

This is how I did it:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "RequiredFieldValidator1.controltovalidate=\"TextBox2\"");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, as I mentioned in the question I have 3 radio buttons, with three sections (one section related to each radio button), each section contains one control that I need to validate, precisely in the first section I have a textbox, a fileupload in the second and dropdownlist in the third. I display a requiredfieldvalidator next to each control. The problem as you can see is that I have multiple RequiredFieldValidators. I'm going to try ValidatorEnable as mentioned in one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Waleed, you do not specify whether you are using ASP.Net forms or ASP.Net MVC.

If you are using ASP.Net MVC, the answer is quite simple...

Firstly, you should create a ModelView class which should include the boolean attributes corresponding with your radiobuttons.

Just use the Foolproof validation library that is available on Codeplex and should work out-of-the-box for your problem: https://foolproof.codeplex.com/

It supports, amongst others, the following "requiredif" validation attributes / decorations:

```
[RequiredIf]
[RequiredIfNot]
[RequiredIfTrue]
[RequiredIfFalse]
[RequiredIfEmpty]
[RequiredIfNotEmpty]
[RequiredIfRegExMatch]
[RequiredIfNotRegExMatch]
```

To get started is easy:

- Download the package from the provided link
- Add a reference to the included .dll file
- Import the included javascript files
- Ensure that your views references the included javascript files from within its HTML for unobtrusive javascript and jquery validation.

All that is then left to do, is to decorate your fields which should be conditionally validated with the `[RequiredIfTrue]` attribute, which should point to the corresponding radiobutton value in your ViewModel.